# Cannot read property 'load' of null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

Im making a code where the viewer count automatically refreshes every 10 seconds. Problem is, nothing is getting outputted, and on the console, it says **cannot read property 'load' of null**

I am using this as my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#viewers').load('ajax.php?request=viewers&id=19').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
define('IN_MYBB', 1); require "./global.php";
require_once MYBB_ROOT."/inc/class_parser.php"; 


switch ($_GET['request']) {

 case 'viewers':
$urlid = $db->escape_string($_GET['id']); // never trust any user inpit
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ****_streams WHERE id='$urlid'");
$row = $db->fetch_array($result);
    echo "Viewers: ".$row['viewers'];
 break;

 case 'contact':

 break;

 default:

 break;

}
?>
```

Can anyone help? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: put your function code inside `$( document ).ready(function() {
});`

Comment: I have tried the methods below, and it stopped the error, but its not showing up on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `$('#viewers')` call is returning null. This is not normal for jQuery, as in every case it would return an object, even if it doesn't include any matching element.
For this reason, I suspect that you may have a problem with loading jQuery. It might just be a conflict with the `$` sign, being handled by some script other tha jQuery, so try using:

```
jQuery('#viewers').load(/*....*/)
```

If that doensn't work either, then it might be that jQuery is not even loaded on your page, so check your script references.

Answer (score 2):

Just taking a guess - most likely your script is executing before the DOM is loaded - since you are using Jquery - you can do this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#viewers').load('ajax.php?request=viewers&id=19').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but you can try change this:

```
$('#viewers').load('ajax.php?request=viewers&id=19').fadeIn("slow");
```

with this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'ajax.php',
   type : 'get',
   data : { request : viewers, id : 19},
   success: function(data){
      $('#viewers').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow')
   },
   error: function(xhr){
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i have tried running this locally. It works perfectly fine for me

Create a separate php file and check it!

text.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['request'])){
    echo "Hello from load";
}else{
    ?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script> <!-- replace with ur jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#output').load('text.php?request=viewers&id=19').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); 

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Content</h2>
<div id='output'>
</div>
</body></html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: IT does work, so my question is, what is preventing from the object loading. Check the url in the first post. Ill finish this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The element with id "viewers" does not exist yet. Move the `<script>` to the end of your document or replace it with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
         $('#viewers').load('ajax.php?request=viewers&id=19').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 10000);
});
```